# How do I get the name of the calling method from another class

Tags: c#, testing, reflection, selenium

I wrote an interface class for Selenium WebDriver which includes an exception handler that records some diagnostic information before rethrowing the exception. It would be easier to diagnose the issue later if I had the name of the method which initiated the Selenium operation. How do I get the name of the method which made the first call into my interface class?

Comment: When posting a question there's a checkbox at the bottom that lets you include an answer with a post. It explains why someone would do this as well.

Comment: @tnw please remove your downvotes to my question and answer. It isn't constructive feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nicest option, if you're using VS 2012, is to use [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx).  This will cause the *compiler* to fill in the method name at compile time, as has no overhead involved.

You would need to add this to your method calls, however:

```
 void YourMethod(string yourFirstArg, [CallerMemberName] string callingMethodName = "")
 {
     //..
```

Note that you can also use `StackTrace` and `StackFrame`, but these have quite a bit of extra overhead involved.

Comment: Maybe my question was a little unclear. The calling method may be from my interface class. If that's the case then this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @carlin.scott An interface can't ever call a method...?

Comment: Well, I guess it would still work but all the other methods would have to pass along the callingMethodName argument but then I would ask the question: Is it better to make simple changes in many places or make a complicated change in one place and how important is a few hundred milliseconds when it's time to collect failure information.

Comment: @carlin.scott It completely depends on how it works - but in general, if you expect this to be a common thing, I'd use this over stack trace info.  Stack Trace info is actually potentially buggy, as it will break in the case of JIT optimizations, etc.

Comment: It's not an interface, it's a class that provides an interface for Selenium. That's why I'm calling it an interface class. Do you have a better name for such a code construct?

Comment: I really can't see a reason to use this over my solution when only considering execution time but the point about the JIT compiler optimizations is a very good one and I wasn't aware of it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Using the System.Diagnostics object you can get a stack-trace and then using linq you can find the most recently added frame that wasn't declared in the current class. Be advised that the JIT compiler may inline some of the methods in the stack during code optimization which would make this less useful.

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1, false).GetFrames().First(f => f.GetMethod().DeclaringType != System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType).GetMethod().Name
```